# gunicorn running django on virtual env

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv, gunicorn

I'm following tutorial from http://www.marinamele.com/2013/12/how-to-set-django-app-on-heroku-part-i.html and I can't pass the section with foreman -> guicorn configuration. My django app is in myproject directory.

When I'm trying to run command from my virtualenv, console freeze, but django app works in my browser - but foreman can't work properly

```
(myenv) ... gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

But when I run:

```
(myenv) ... gunicorn myproject:wsgi
```

I got **Failed to find application: 'myproject'**.

my requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.6.5
argparse==1.2.1
gunicorn==19.0.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might of some help;
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

especially below 2 lines

This requires that your project be on the Python path; the simplest way to ensure that is to run this command from the same directory as your manage.py file

Comment: I do it, django starts in my browser but in my console not shown any messages that process is listening